# append elements of 4 lists into a single list in an alternating pattern in Python

Tags: python

I have 4 lists of numbers:

```
a = [  1,   2,   3,   4 ... 100]
b = [101, 102, 103, 104 ... 200] 
c = [201, 202, 203, 204 ... 300]
d = [301, 302, 303, 304 ... 400]
```

and I want to append them into a new list `e` in a pattern of:

```
- use 4 elements from a, 
- then 3 elements from b, 
- then 2 elements from c, 
- then 2 elements from d
repeat until all lists are exhausted
```

and continues this pattern till all the elements are appended into the new list `e` so it looks like:

```
e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 101, 102, 103, 201, 202, 301, 302, 5, 6, 7, 8...]
```

If `a` is exhausted, the loop should continue with the remaining 3 lists in the same pattern of 3:2:2 until all lists are exhausted.

How do I do it?

Comment: Please show us your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `roundrobin` from the [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) or imported from [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.roundrobin), on repeated iterators ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZJNb9swDIbv/hVEe7AVOEZjrx8IkAH9HHZtj0FgODLTaHEkQ2bW5NdnpLKmdnWgTT3iS5Fie6C1s8XxuPJuC4bQk3NNB2bbOk@gD7rBFEzXGI1RVOMKvNvZ2rulsclIzlfLBjs1jYDXRQ/G9w@PcQrxk5jnl1jBePwT7uEJnuEBXuDxIoRcwitq0yJojzXr1UAOfqHz7whv1WZjunDM7rZlpcn8RZhBgzb5Sn3iuKeOUbhwgGxUVpYCyhJWznN1YCx8C/xYmwZ78qdCZJE/fDmyREPkRCXkG2JZB4NNHWCizhD3GluCN3Ltb0lOxtlhqDRh67g2WuPpgsS5PhD@7Dri@HXFX25NeCQ5E8rMBhq9Do1nMBmyYXfCayZhM@3FKRVFlbTXdJT4yr5jMklhcjVhsPy2f8UkD0QPSS6kCKQekkLIj0Ci1htLSYz7FjVNYS5qHMY8JBSTiylCFjF5UBXDf9cp3KRwm8JdlmWLWEUyFfNRfzTnYQYqtRix5H9vyV5x9jR7@dmrxVOLz5t57HYNTXl2UR2P/wA)):

```
e = [*roundrobin(*[iter(a)]*4, *[iter(b)]*3, *[iter(c)]*2, *[iter(d)]*2)]
```

Same thing written differently ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZLfb6MwDMff@Sus3QNkStHabnenSjtpP0973R6rCkFw19wgQcG9tX99Z6faCosiA/nYX8fG3Z423s0Ph3XwLVjCQN43Pdi284HA7E2DGmzfWINJUuMagt@6OvjKuuxc/MuqwV4tEuB1NoDpze1dqiG9F/PwmCqYTP7ADdzDA9zCI9ydxZAf8IzGdggmYM16NZCHv@jDK8JL@fZm@@jmtm1RGrL/Ea6hQZedUh857qhnFC8cIRuVF4WAooC1D1wdWAffAt83tsGB/LEQWRT2pw9ZoiFyohLzjbGsvcWmjjBTXxB3BjuCF/LdkyQn6904VJrQeq6NNni8IHGud4R/2544flPyk1sTf5L4xDLzkcagQ5NrmI7ZuDvxb2bxUA/ilEqSUtpre8pC6V4xm2qYXkwZVN/OL5jMIjFjMhMyj6Qek7mQy0iSLlhHWYq7Dg0tYClqHMY8JhQzEzOPWcTMoqoYfrvS8FPDLw2/8zxfpSopNVQajAbJ2ZZdnAANy9P5SiUyOsvzwYgy/drV5zZHf95q9XnPgP22oQVPMqrD4QM)):

```
a, b, c, d = map(iter, [a, b, c, d])
e = [*roundrobin(a, a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, d, d)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it even without any imports - leveraging loops and your own iterators - but it is going to be more lines of code:

```
# range reduced for output reasons, can do 1,101 etc as well
ia = iter(range(1,11))
ib = iter(range(11,21))
ic = iter(range(21,31))
id = iter(range(31,41))

# how many items to use per iterator
mapping = {ia: 4, ib: 3, ic: 2, ic: 2}

x = []
# do while any iterator left inside mapping
while mapping:
    xl = len(x)
    remove = []
    # loop over all iterators and apply the step wise addition
    for (iterator, step) in mapping.items():
        for _ in range(step):
            v = next(iterator, None)
            if v is not None:
                x.append(v)
            else:
                remove.append(iterator)
                break

  # iterator is done, remove key
  for key in remove:
      del mapping[key]

print(x)
```

Output (manually formatted):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4,     11, 12, 13,     21, 22,      31, 32,
 5, 6, 7, 8,     14, 15, 16,     23, 24,      33, 34,
 9, 10,          17, 18, 19,     25, 26,      35, 36,
                 20,             27, 28,      37, 38,
                                 29, 30,      39, 40]
```